# Displaying Images beside text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i  make a code of images beside text in my flutter app like this picture below:
[image beside text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkHqG.jpg)

Comment: What did you try and didn't work for you ?

Comment: i used a leading:Image.network() inside ListTile but the image is displayed is very big and the text in list is gone

Comment: Now I have an idea about your problem, but it'll be very convenient for me and other members to help you if you shared the snippet where you're facing the problem.

Comment: ok i'll edit my question

Comment: Try wrapping Image.network() with ClipRect().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to Row widget to show image and text side by side , your problem well be in image width , so you can but the image as background image to avoid image  stretch size issues , see this example :

```
Row(
children: <Wigdet>[
  Container(
   width:100,
   height: 100,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     image: ImageDecoration: NetworkImage("youImageLink")
   )
  ),
  Text("your text")
]
);
```